# C# graphics displays the image larger than normal?

Tags: c#, graphics

I am trying to merge two images using C Sharp's System.Drawing.Graphics.

Here is my code:

```
        Point p = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(OffsetX), Convert.ToInt32(OffsetY));
        Image i = Image.FromFile("1.jpg");
        Image toDraw = Image.FromFile("2.jpg");
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(i))
        {
            g.DrawImage(toDraw, p);
            g.Save();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "saved"));
            i.Save(Path.Combine("saved", "saved1.jpg"));
        }
```

The code works fine, but the second image is enlarged in the output from the program.

Made with Paint:

[image]

Made with code above:

[image]

Comment: perhaps c# is compensating for different DPIs on the two images?

Comment: The rectangle worked beautifully. Thanks everyone, especially David, I assume you embedded the images?

Comment: Yes I did the images. Hans did the hard bit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload to control the size of the image.  The overload you are using takes note of the Image.HorizontalResolution and VerticalResolution properties to ensure that the drawn image is (roughly) as large in inches as it was when it was created.  Fix:

```
       g.DrawImage(toDraw, new Rectangle(p, new Size(i.Width, i.Height)));
```